# Not able to reach azure public IP from corporate network

Tags: azure, networking

We have an Azure Application gateway that has a connected azure public IP.

I can reach this public IP when I use any device not connected to our corp network.
However, I am not able to reach this public IP from my computer connected to our corporate network.

This is what I have found out so far:

- I am able to ping it from my computer, and it responds.
- When I disconnect my laptop from the corporate network and use my cellphone as a 4g modem I am able to reach the public IP successfully.
- I am not able to see the failed requests in the access log for the application gateway

Traceroute when I am connected via 4g (not corp network)
(Obfuscated the destination IP)

```
Tracing the path to DESTINATION on TCP port 443 (https), 40 hops max
 1  172.20.10.1  13.363 ms  4.620 ms  3.922 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  ti0275c360-ae8-0.ti.telenor.net (146.172.23.13)  52.672 ms  49.293 ms  37.013 ms
 6  10.67.115.189  43.385 ms  35.832 ms  49.106 ms
 7  10.67.115.190  32.485 ms  37.096 ms  52.809 ms
 8  ti0001a401-ae18-21.ti.telenor.net (213.142.76.153)  67.955 ms  38.419 ms  40.676 ms
 9  ti0275c360-ae49-0.ti.telenor.net (146.172.22.98)  40.951 ms  106.652 ms  52.218 ms
10  ti0300b400-ae1-0.ti.telenor.net (146.172.105.69)  79.811 ms  37.768 ms  39.888 ms
11  148.122.9.22  58.792 ms  68.895 ms  40.196 ms
12  ae23-0.icr02.osl22.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.235.74)  51.590 ms  50.033 ms  74.065 ms
13  be-102-0.ibr01.osl22.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.33.67)  59.031 ms  79.027 ms  77.198 ms
14  be-5-0.ibr01.got30.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.7.115)  79.174 ms  56.404 ms  92.066 ms
15  104.44.31.5  64.108 ms  75.563 ms  51.695 ms
16  be-4-0.ibr01.ham30.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.16.128)  120.492 ms  65.839 ms  53.344 ms
17  be-12-0.ibr05.ams06.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.30.71)  62.325 ms  57.971 ms  60.787 ms
18  ae142-0.icr04.ams06.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.21.186)  66.787 ms  116.627 ms  78.765 ms
19  * * *
20  * * *
----
30  * * *
31  myhost.com (DESTINATION) [open]  85.554 ms  92.767 ms  62.342 ms
```

Traceroute when I am connected to the corp network:

```
Tracing the path to DESTINATION on TCP port 443 (https), 40 hops max
 1  10.200.4.2  5.690 ms  6.611 ms  5.644 ms
 2  10.1.230.161  4.084 ms  4.004 ms  5.682 ms
 3  10.1.230.1  4.655 ms  4.260 ms  6.372 ms
 4  10.1.230.2  5.684 ms  8.037 ms  6.841 ms
 5  10.254.254.1  7.765 ms  5.302 ms  8.707 ms
 6  GATEWAY        5.376 ms * 10.592 ms
 7  FIREWALL       29.380 ms  4.791 ms  7.179 ms
 8  9.62-97-202.bkkb.no (62.97.202.9)  6.846 ms  8.001 ms  8.859 ms
 9  bkk-u-gw.bkkb.no (193.28.236.246)  16.958 ms  11.596 ms  13.988 ms
10  ba-u-gw-2.bkkb.no (193.28.236.245)  17.979 ms  19.062 ms  14.600 ms
11  bkkdigitek.ier02.osl30.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.198.93)  27.989 ms  18.077 ms  17.081 ms
12  ae23-0.icr02.osl22.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.235.74)  13.404 ms  12.878 ms  12.583 ms
13  be-122-0.ibr02.osl22.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.33.71)  35.195 ms  33.573 ms  58.699 ms
14  be-4-0.ibr02.got30.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.7.111)  53.509 ms  33.173 ms  35.394 ms
15  104.44.31.13  32.072 ms  31.094 ms  33.823 ms
16  be-6-0.ibr01.sao30.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.7.178)  34.454 ms  31.597 ms  30.273 ms
17  be-12-0.ibr06.ams06.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.30.73)  148.238 ms  34.973 ms  43.711 ms
18  ae160-0.icr03.ams06.ntwk.msn.net (104.44.21.200)  37.458 ms  31.314 ms  39.204 ms
19  * * *
20  * * *
---
39  * * *
40  * * *
Destination not reached
```

I am not sure whether this is a network issue or an application gateway/azure issue. As far as I understand the internal network is not to blame due to the fact that the trace reaches internet, but never reaches the destination.

Does anyone know what needs to be done to be able to reach the public IP from inside our corp network?

Answer (score 0):

Check your firewall log and see what is being returned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).